# Selectively removing node labels in D3 force directed diagram

Tags: graph, d3.js, force-layout

Overall context: I have a db of cross-references among pages in a wiki space, and want an incrementally-growing visualization of links.

I have working code that shows clusters of labels as you mouseover. But when you move away, rather than hiding *all* the labels, I want to keep certain key labels (e.g. the centers of clusters).

I forked an existing example and got it roughly working.

- info is at http://webseitz.fluxent.com/wiki/WikiGraphBrowser
- near the bottom of that or any other page in that space, in the block that starts with "BackLinks:", at the end you'll find "Click here for WikiGraphBrowser" which will launch a window with the interface
- equivalent static subset example visible at http://www.wikigraph.net/static/d3/cgmartin/WikiGraphBrowser/:

[image]

- code for that example is at https://github.com/BillSeitz/WikiGraphBrowser/blob/master/js/wiki_graph.js

Code that works at removing all labels:

```
i = j = 0;
if (!bo) { //bo=False - from mouseout
    //labels.select('text.label').remove();
        labels.filter(function(o) {
        return !(o.name in clicked_names);
        })
        .text(function(o) { return ""; });
        j++;
}
```

Code attempting to leave behind some labels, which does *not* work:

```
labels.forEach(function(o) {
    if (!(d.name in clicked_names)) {
        d.text.label.remove();
    }
```

I know I'm just not grokking the d3 model at all....
thx

Comment: Have you tried amending the filter function in your working solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes down to your use of `in` to search for a name in an array.  The Javascript `in` keyword searches *object keys* not *object values*.  For an array, the keys are the index values.  So testing `(d.name in clicked_names)` will always return false.

Try

```
i = j = 0;
    if (!bo) { //bo=False - from mouseout
        //labels.select('text.label').remove();
         labels.filter(function(o) {
            return (clicked_names.indexOf(o.name) < 0);
            })
            .text(function(o) { return ""; });
            j++;

    }
```

The [array `.indexOf(object)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method returns -1 if none of the elements in the array are equal (by triple-equals standards) to the parameter.  Alternatively, if you are trying to support IE8 (I'm assuming not, since you're using SVG), you could use a [`.some(function)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) test.

By the way, there's a difference between removing a label and just setting it's text content to the empty string.  Which one to use will depend on whether you want to show the text again later.  Either way, just be sure you don't end up with a proliferation of empty labels clogging up your browser.

Comment: For extra credit: can end up re-painting labels that don't get faded lots of times, making them rather messy looking. Best way to check for  existing non-null label and avoid painting?

Comment: Within your filter function, `this` will refer to the `<text>` element itself, so you can check whether it has a non-empty `textContent` property, and therefore doesn't need to be included in the filter: `function(o) { return ( (this.textContent) && (clicked_names.indexOf(o.name) < 0 ) ); })`.  Specifying the two filters in that order also makes sure that you only check the clicked names array for the labels that currently have text content, so that will be faster as well.